# SWIFT: Parse column is not appending into array

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'd like to append the 'userVotes' column in the following parse table into an array using Swift -

[image]

Here is my code -

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class MusicPlaylistTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var usernames = [String]()
var songs = [String]()
var voters = [String]()

var numVotes = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.grayColor()

    let query = PFQuery(className:"PlaylistData")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            if let objects = objects! as? [PFObject] {

                self.usernames.removeAll()
                self.songs.removeAll()
                self.voters.removeAll()

                for object in objects {

                    let username = object["username"] as? String
                    self.usernames.append(username!)

                    let track = object["song"] as? String
                    self.songs.append(track!)

                    let title = object["userVotes"]! as? String
                    self.voters.append(title!)
                    print("Array: \(self.voters)")

                }

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        } else {

            print(error)
        }
    }


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return usernames.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellTrack", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TrackTableViewCell

    //cell.username.text = usernames[indexPath.row]
    cell.username.text = usernames[indexPath.row]
    cell.songTitle.text = songs[indexPath.row]
    cell.votes.text = "\(numVotes)"

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {



}


}
```

I would like the parse array column to append as follows - 
[["user1,"user5,"user9"],["user1,"user2,"user3"],["user4,"user5,"user6"],...]

At this point, I'm getting the following runtime error - fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each object that is in your "userVotes" is an array and your you've declared

```
var voters = [String]()
```

which is not right because you're saying that there will be one element being appended which is not the case.

So, you should declare voters as...

```
var voters = Array<Array<String>>()
```

then as you are downloading it,

```
for object in objects {
    let title = object["userVotes"]! as? [String]
    self.voters.append(title!)
    print("Array: \(self.voters)")
}
```